# DefaultControllerFactory.RequestContext replacement when migrating from MVC1 to MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am migrating an old 3rd party project from MVC1 to MVC2, which I am not very familiar with. One of the documented breaking change in MVC2 is "Changes to the DefaultControllerFactory class break custom controller factories that derive from it" as mentioned [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc#_TOC3_1). I have multiple locations in project code similar to below sample which returns following error.

> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory does not contain a definition
>   for 'RequestContext' and no extension method 'RequestContext'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    public static class DataUtil
{
        private static readonly DefaultControllerFactory Factory =
            ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory() as DefaultControllerFactory;

        private static void SetGridCookies(string orderByProperty, string sortDirection, int page, int pageSize)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["GridCookie"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("GridCookie"));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["GridCookie"].Expires.AddMinutes(1);
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["GridCookie"]["PageSize"] = pageSize.ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["GridCookie"][string.Format("{0}_SortColumnName", Factory.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["pageName"])] = orderByProperty;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["GridCookie"]["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["GridCookie"][string.Format("{0}_CurrentPage", Factory.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["pageName"])] = page.ToString();
        }     
}
```

How can this code rewritten to be compatible with MVC2? Thank you.